# Finding tangent point coordinates on a circle?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[image: Problem Image]
Given
x1,y1,
d,
r,
and x2,y2

How would I find x3,y3 and x4,y4?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about trigonometry and [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

Construct two equations.

At first, tangent vector `P31=(x3-x1, y3-y1)` should be perpendicular to radius-vector `P32=(x3-x2, y3-y2)`, so dot product of these vectors is zero.

At second, squared length of `P31` is expressed through `d` and `r` using Pythagorean theorem.

Then solve system of two equations and get two solutions for both tangent points.

Note that this task has little relation to programming - it is just math.